# vscode http.proxy settings does not work, but command line "--proxy" works

Tags: visual-studio-code, http-proxy

I configure my proxy in settings.json as recommended, it doesn't work.

`{"http.proxy": "http://user@myproxy:port",
  "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
 }`

But if I use it by command as below, it works:

```
pip install Pylint --proxy=http://user@myproxy:port
```

Could you please help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a try with bellow:

1. start vscode with below command

   > code --proxy-server="xxx.xx.xx.xx:port"
2. add command in desktop for vscode

   /usr/share/applications/code.desktop

   > Exec=/usr/share/code/code --proxy-server="xx.x.x.xx:xxx" --unity-launch %F